Short story where a captive spirit entity was used to defeat other spirit-realm entities
There was a story in a collection by a Japanese writer 90% sure.  A “spirit” entity was being held captive and used to defeat other spirit-realm entities.  Maybe captor was descendant of Nazis or some predecessors who had learned how to do this.
Would love to know author, how to find it. And if he ever developed it into a longer story

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Was it a physical book or an e-book?  Do you recall the cover art of the collection?

I doubt I'm correct, but I'm submitting JoJo's Bizarre Adventure just to be sure:

Characters use "Stands" (first described as spirits) to fight each other
One character is a Nazi (although not in the season with the spirits)
Written by Hirohiko Araki (Japanese Mangaka)
The predecessors/descendants are very important to the story

